# Sendto returns -1 and errno 22 (Invalid argument), when set the multicast outgoing interface by ip_mreqn

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, network-programming

I faced an issue, when I try to send to multicast group by setting the intended outgoing interface by the code bellow, Actually when the condition is TRUE `(if(config.enable_if == 1))` the sendto system call returns error `Invalid Argument`, but if the condition was False sendto send data and doesn't generate any error.

Please Anyone has an idea, or should I modify anything in my code?

```
    /* Create a datagram socket on which to send. */
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    /* Set local interface for outbound multicast datagrams. */
    /* The IP address specified must be associated with a local */
    /* multicast capable interface. */
    if(config.enable_if == 1){
       mreqn.imr_ifindex = if_nametoindex("eth3");
       rc = setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (void *)&mreqn, sizeof(mreqn));
     }

    /* Initialize the group sockaddr structure with a */
    /* group address of dynamic address and port dynamic port. */
    memset((char *) &groupSock, 0, sizeof(groupSock));
    groupSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    groupSock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(config.mip);
    groupSock.sin_port = htons(config.port);


    /* Send a message to the multicast group specified by the*/
    /* groupSock sockaddr structure. */

    rc = sendto(sd, (const char *)& databuf, datalen, 0, (const struct sockaddr*)&groupSock, sizeof (struct sockaddr));
    printf("errno %d\n",errno);
```

Comment: What is `databuf` and how is it declared? Same with `datalen`?

Comment: Also, do **not** check `errno` unless you know the previous call failed. You must always check the return code first. And you don't check for failure from the `setsockopt` call either.

Comment: You should check if setsockopt() fails, if it does, it might provide further clues. And you cannot inspect errno after sendto() unless sendto() fails. If sendto does not fail, who knows what errno is.

Comment: yes I do but i didn't added them here. rc is =-1 , char *databuf = malloc(1024) .... but don't care about these things please just focus on the scenario

Comment: and I check for sesockopt too don't worry

Comment: @HatemMashaqi The point is then that you should post the actual code, so we don't have to ask all these questions, we can only see the errors in the code posted, not the errors you see on your screen. One thing that's wrong though is sizeof (struct sockaddr),It needs to be the size of your actual address. In this case: `sizeof groupSock`

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I tried that sizeof(groupSock) but it doesn't work too.. Did you try before:

Comment: Did u try this before: mreqn.imr_ifindex = if_nametoindex("eth3");
       rc = setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (void *)&mreqn, sizeof(mreqn));

Comment: I try this method before and it worked :                                                   localInterface.s_addr = inet_addr(config.sip);

rc = setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char *)&localInterface, sizeof(localInterface));              but that one above it fails :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason `sendto` fails is because you pass it a data pointer it does not expect. If you have `char* databuf` and you then do `&databuf` you get the address of the pointer, i.e. a pointer to a pointer, of type `char**`. If you remove the cast (which is not needed) then you will get at least a warning or maybe even an error when compiling.